# Test fails in ember

Tags: testing, ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I'm facing some problems figuring out how to pass a test in Ember.

The thing is, I'm trying to use [NProgress](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/) in my project, but I can't pass my tests.

I'm following [this example](https://topaxi.codes/ember-js-route-progress-with-nprogress-js/) to create a mixing for it, and everything is working fine, besides the tests.

That's the mixing I created:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
NProgress.configure({ showSpinner: true });

export default Ember.Mixin.create({  
  actions: {
    loading() {
      if(!Ember.$('.nprogress-busy').length) {
            if(Ember.$('#content').length) {
              Ember.$('#content').removeClass('fadeIn');
              Ember.$('#content').addClass('animated fadeOut');
            }
            if(Ember.$('#page-content-wrapper').length) {
              Ember.$('#page-content-wrapper').removeClass('fadeIn');
              Ember.$('#page-content-wrapper').addClass('animated fadeOut');
            } 
          NProgress.start();
        }   
      this.router.one('didTransition', function () {
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
          setTimeout(function(){
            if(Ember.$('#content').length) {
              Ember.$('#content').removeClass('fadeOut');
              Ember.$('#content').addClass('animated fadeIn');
            }
            if(Ember.$('#page-content-wrapper').length) {
              Ember.$('#page-content-wrapper').removeClass('fadeOut');
              Ember.$('#page-content-wrapper').addClass('animated fadeIn');
            }
          }, 1000);
          NProgress.done();
            return true;
      });
    }, 
      error() {
        NProgress.done();
        return true;
      }
  }
});
```

And that's what is failing:

```
not ok 80 PhantomJS 2.0 - JSHint - mixins: mixins/loading-indicator.js should pass jshint
---
    actual: >
        false
    expected: >
        true
    message: >
        mixins/loading-indicator.js should pass jshint.
        mixins/loading-indicator.js: line 2, col 1, 'NProgress' is not defined.
        mixins/loading-indicator.js: line 16, col 11, 'NProgress' is not defined.
        mixins/loading-indicator.js: line 30, col 11, 'NProgress' is not defined.
        mixins/loading-indicator.js: line 35, col 9, 'NProgress' is not defined.

        4 errors
    Log: |
...
```

As you can see, I can use NProgress without any problems on the application, but as I'm not declaring NProgress anywhere the test fails.

Does anyone have an idea about how I could pass it?

I know there are similar components in ember, but I chose to use NProgress because I can set when I want it to start, and when I want it finish. I didn't want to use a progress bar where I would need to set a time for the animation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

there are two ways to make this JSHint check pass:

- Add `NProgress` to the [predef section of your `.jshintrc`](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#using-global-variables-or-external-scripts)
- Add [`/* globals NProgress: false */`](http://jshint.com/docs/) to the top of any file that uses that variable.

I have linked to the appropriate Ember CLI and JSHint documentations for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @locks , unfortunately I've moved to another solution, but I'll remember it next time something like it happen!